# SQLite query: multiple select union

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following tables:

Table: `table1`

```
id | timestamp  | val
1  | 1577644027 | 0
2  | 1577644028 | 0
3  | 1577644029 | 1
4  | 1577644030 | 1
5  | 1577644031 | 2
6  | 1577644032 | 2
7  | 1577644033 | 3
8  | 1577644034 | 2
9  | 1577644035 | 1
10 | 1577644036 | 0
11 | 1577644037 | 1
12 | 1577644038 | 1
13 | 1577644039 | 1
14 | 1577644040 | 0
```

Table: `table2`

```
id | idFirst | idLast | val
1  |   3     |   9    |  0
2  |   11    |   13   |  13
```

I want to perform a query that programatically gets the timestamp difference between the registers referenced from `table2` to `table1` where the timestamp of `idFirst` and `idLast` is between the given timestamps (`idFirst>firstInputTimestamp && idLast<lastInputTimestamp`).

That is to say, in the case of `id`=1 of `table2`, it should be the difference between `1577644035` and `1577644029` (`6`). In the case of `id`=2, the difference would be `1577644039-1577644037` (`2`).

My non-working approach of what I am trying is as follows:

```
SELECT timestamp2-timestamp1
(SELECT timestamp FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT idFirst FROM table2) ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS timestamp1,
(SELECT timestamp FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT idLast FROM table2) ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS timestamp2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may join the first table to the second table *twice*, once for each id, and then take the difference:

```
SELECT
    t2.id,
    t1b.timestamp - t1a.timestamp AS difference,
    t2.val
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1a ON t2.idFirst = t1a.id
LEFT JOIN table1 t1b ON t2.idLast = t1b.id
ORDER BY
    t2.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess an absolute could do the trick.

```
SELECT T2.id, abs(T11.timestamp - T12.timestamp)
FROM table2 T2
INNER JOIN table1 T11 ON T2.idFirst = T11.id
INNER JOIN table1 T12 ON T2.idSecond = T12.id
```